# tabbing with vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

I made the mistake of posting this on the unix echange originally beore realizing ubuntu had a separate site.

I'm using Ubuntu with vim as my text editor of choice. I know some people set shortcuts to switch from one tab to the next with vim. The default is g t and g T, but I find this to be clumsy and not natural. I'd like to set my aliases so I can switch to the left tab with f5, and the right with f8. I am unsure of how to change the vimrc page to get this result. Thank you!

Comment: Well.. What would you do I said there's a site for Vim too: [vi.se]?

Comment: I would be pleasantly surprised. I didn't think it would be a separate exchange. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general syntax for mapping keys is:

```
{cmd} {attr} {lhs} {rhs}

where
{cmd}  is one of ':map', ':map!', ':nmap', ':vmap', ':imap',
       ':cmap', ':smap', ':xmap', ':omap', ':lmap', etc.
{attr} is optional and one or more of the following: <buffer>, <silent>,
       <expr> <script>, <unique> and <special>.
       More than one attribute can be specified to a map.
{lhs}  left hand side, is a sequence of one or more keys that you will use
       in your new shortcut.
{rhs}  right hand side, is the sequence of keys that the {lhs} shortcut keys
       will execute when entered.
```

So you can try adding the following codes in your `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <F5> gt
nnoremap <F8> gT
```

There are detailed tutorials available elsewhere, see:

1. [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))
2. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/create-custom-keybindings-in-vim/
3. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages

Comment: I had tried this, but I thought I was supposed to put a space between. Thanks for the answer and thanks for the resources!

Comment: You are most welcome!